# Restrict GKSession to Wifi and ignore Bluetooth

Tags: ios, bluetooth, wifi, game-center

I am implementing an IOS game using Bluetooth, Wifi and Game Center; Bluetooth is a two person game using GKPeerPickerController, the Wifi version runs on the local network and is a 4 to 6 player game that needs auto discovery and thus I am configuring my own GKSession, the Game Center game uses GKMatch to spread the game across the web.

All of this works well except where Bluetooth and Wireless are available in the situation where I want to play a multi-player game on the local wireless network.  The fact that bluetooth is turned on slows down and interferes with the auto discovery process.  It works like a dream when Bluetooth is turned off but it would be wrong to programmatically turn off bluetooth.

My Question: Is there anyway to tell a GKSession to ignore Bluetooth and restrict itself to the local wifi.  The GKPeerPickerContoller has a connectionTypesMask which allows you to specify Bluetooth or Wireless but with 4 to six players this would get very chatty, the GKSession does not seem to have this option.